# How can I use a regex variable in a query for MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to make query MongoDB for documents based on a regex expression that I contruct. For e.g
I have constructed a simple regex as follows that is a combination of a random letter and a random number for in Nodejs

```
var randnum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var alpha = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','X','Y','Z'];
var randletter = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
var val = randletter + randnum + '.*;
```

I have tried various combinations for the regex variable like

```
var stream = collection.find({"FirstName": /val/).stream();
&&
var stream = collection.find({"FirstName": /$val/).stream();
&&
var stream = collection.find({"FirstName": {$in : [{$regex:val}]}}).stream()
&&
var stream = collection.find({"FirstName": {$in : [{$regex:$val}]}}).stream()
```

None o it seem to work. However when I write the actual regex I get the records for e.g.

```
var stream = collection.find({"FirstName": /J.*/).stream();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Ganesh

Comment: Wizard, Thanks. However, this did not seem to work.var stream = collection.find({"FirstName": {$regex:val}}).stream();
 stream.on("data", function(item) 
                        results.push(item);

Comment: Any error occurs, or just doesn't get the expected result? Example of a document stored in the database may be helpful.

Answer (score 58):

I was having same problem with my title and after lots of searching, i found this answer [Here](https://xuguoming.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/using-variable-regex-with-mongodb-query-in-node-js/),

```
var search = 'Joe';
db.users.find(name: /^search/)
db.users.find(name: {$regex: /^search/});
db.users.find(name: {$regex: "/^" + search + "/"});
```

The queries above won’t return anything. The solution to this little problem is quite simple:

```
db.users.find(name: new RegExp(search)) //For substring search, case sensitive. 
db.users.find(name: new RegExp('^' + search + '$')) //For exact search, case sensitive
db.users.find(name: new RegExp(search， ‘i')) //For substring search, case insensitive
db.users.find(name: new RegExp('^' +search + '$', 'i')); //For exact search, case insensitive
```

Other flags or properties can be added base on reference here

Comment: `db.users.find(name: {$regex: "/^" + search + "/"});` exactly what I needed

Comment: For me it didn't work using the `/`. Like in this example: 
`var name = '.*'+user.name+'.*'
found = db.users.findOne({
    'name': {$regex: name}
})
`

Comment: i was exactly looking for db.users.find(name: new RegExp('^' +search + '$', 'i'));
thanks..

Comment: Hamza :  I am facing an issue with `case insensitive`  and `exact search` . The rule I have added is as follows  {name: new RegExp('^' + search + '$' , "i")} . The prolem is that when I search `test...` (with dots, which I need since there is entry with dots) , I got results `test123`, `test333` etc.... How can I get only entry `test...`

Comment: It's not working with MongoDB. It's passing "search" as a string as supposed to value of the variable.

Answer (score 49):

You need to create a regular expression object from the string using the `RegExp` constructor as the `/.../` syntax is only for use with literals.

```
var stream = collection.find({"FirstName": new RegExp(val)}).stream();
```

Comment: JohnnyHK - That worked awfully well. The changes I made were  var val =  randletter + ".*" + randnum + ".*";                                  var stream = collection.find({"FirstName": new RegExp(val)}).stream();                                            Thanks Ganesh

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, but it didn't seem to work. What I have to do is, let pattern = '/^\/'+ cat + '/';
col.find({name: new RegExp(pattern)}) where cat is a variable whose value I am concatenating to create pattern for matching.

Comment: Remove the `/` characters from `pattern` and it will work. @AvaniKhabiya

Answer (score 11):

Use the following code to use dynamic value in regex with or operations

```
{$match: { $or: [{ 'title': { $regex:  request.query.val, $options: 'i'} }, { 'skills_required': { $regex:  request.query.val, $options: 'i'} }] }},
```

Comment: $or: [{users: { $elemMatch: { name: { $regex: `${filters.userName}`, $options: 'i' } } },}]; 
  . . .. . . .great answer! also works with string interpolation  e.g.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use the variable **val** as a parameter of the query part, you can use **$regex**, for example:

```
collection.find({"FirstName": {$regex:val}})
```

It is not allowed to put **$regex** in **$in** operator according to the manual.

If you want to put regular expression object in **$in** operator, you have to use JavaScript regular expression object, for example:

```
collection.find({"FirstName": {$in: [/abc/, /123/]}})
```

By the way, **val** in `/val/` is constant string, not the variable as you defined above.

Comment: Hi -Thanks. But it did not work - var val =  randletter + randnum + '.*';    var stream = collection.find({"FirstName": {$regex:val}}).stream(); Regards Ganesh

Comment: @TinniamV.Ganesh, What's value of **FirstName** in database? Or maybe just no items can satisfy your query needs?

Comment: Wizard - Firstname is just a string of letters and numbers. I tried it a couple of times it always returned an empty set. The other version var stream = collection.find({"FirstName": new RegExp(val)}).stream(); worked. Thanks anyway. Regards Ganesh

Comment: @TinniamV.Ganesh, Thanks for the reply. I think I missed some details about your circumstances which do not support $regex.

Answer (score 8):

If your regex includes a variable, make sure to [escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#escaping) it.

```
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}
```

This can be used like this

```
new RegExp(escapeRegExp(searchString), 'i')
```

Or in a mongoDb query like this

```
{ '$regex': escapeRegExp(searchString) }
```

Posted same comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610131/checking-if-a-field-contains-a-string/65922692#65922692)

Answer (score 3):

```
let test = `what your regex should search`;

collection.find({
    fieldName: {$regex: test}
}).then(result => red.send(result));
```

// tested on mongoose but should work on mongodb too

Answer (score 0):

My use case was to fetch results **STARTS WITH** a given query, and below solution worked for me.

```
let q = '^' + query;
return await User.find({ name: { $regex: q, $options: 'i' } }).select('name').limit(10);
```