# MongoDB query on object name substring

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have uploaded the following JSON file into a mongoDB database:
https://cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/static/data/pricelist.json

I have succeeded in accessing it using the following line in my app.js:

```
 db.googlepricelist.find({}, 
  {"gcp_price_list":1}).pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res);
```

I would like to query all objects in object `gcp_price_list`, where the name of the object contains substring "VMIMAGE". 
So for example bellow objects:

```
"CP-COMPUTEENGINE-VMIMAGE-F1-MICRO"
"CP-COMPUTEENGINE-VMIMAGE-G1-SMALL"
```

I can't figure out how to define a query which is able to do this.

So far I tried this:

```
    db.googlepricelist.find({$where: function() {
    for (var key in this.gcp_price_list) {
        if (key.indexOf("VMIMAGE")!=-1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
},}).pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching for value of any field in MongoDB without explicitly naming it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790819/searching-for-value-of-any-field-in-mongodb-without-explicitly-naming-it)

Comment: From there I figured that
`db.googlepricelist.find({$where: function() {
        for (var key in this) {
            if (key.indexOf("VMIMAGE")!=-1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    },}).pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res);`
might work, but unfortunately it does not.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going and works from v3.4.4 onwards:

```
db.googlepricelist.aggregate({
    $project: {
        "gcp_price_list_as_array": { $objectToArray: "$gcp_price_list" }, // transform "gcp_price_list" into an array of key-value pairs
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$gcp_price_list_as_array" // flatten array
}, {
    $match: { "gcp_price_list_as_array.k": /VMIMVAGE/ } // like filter on the "k" (as in "key") field using regular expression
})
```

You'd normally attempt to use $filter to filter the array which, however, doesn't work using a regular expression. There's an open [JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947) for that but it's simply not yet available.

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot! It works perfectly. Is there any way to only return the price list? Right now I have to do `result[0].gcp_price_list_as_array` to get the first object, but I would prefer to do `gcp_price_list_as_array[0]`
Is that possible?
Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... The aggregation query returns a **list of** matching documents. As a consequence you will have to either iterate that list or access a specific item like result[0]. Can you perhaps rephrase your question?

Comment: Nevermind, I found a solution for that myself. I do have one more question though. Can I store VMIMAGE in a variable of some sort? So that I can say /variablename/ .

Comment: Yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699885/how-can-i-use-a-regex-variable-in-a-query-for-mongodb