# using reqular expression to querying mongoodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I try to get data from mongoodb by querying find a field name. i use regular expression to get that data. for example if set const name = 'st' then i will get 'steven','stephanie','stella'.

```
      const name = req.params.str;
      const user = await User.find({ "name": {$regex:`/${name}/`}});
      console.log(user);
```

i try the code above and the result is null

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699885/how-can-i-use-a-regex-variable-in-a-query-for-mongodb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use a regex variable in a query for MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699885/how-can-i-use-a-regex-variable-in-a-query-for-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex in a query like this:

```
var regex = /^someRegex/i; // It's a regex obj no double quote here
var query = { name: { $regex: regex } };
```