# Find documents which contain a particular value - Mongo, Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to add a search option to my website but it doesn't work. I looked up solutions but they all refer to using an actual string, whereas in my case I'm using a variable, and I can't make those solutions work. Here is my code:

```
cursor = source.find({'title': search_term}).limit(25)
for document in cursor:
    result_list.append(document)
```

Unfortunately this only gives back results which match the search_term variable's value exactly. I want it to give back any results where the title contains the search term - regardless what other strings it contains. How can I do it if I want to pass a variable to it, and not an actual string? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$regex` to do contains searches.

```
cursor = collection.find({'field': {'$regex':'regular expression'}})
```

And to make it case insensitive:

```
cursor = collection.find({'field': {'$regex':'regular expression', '$options'‌​:'i'}})
```

Please try `cursor = source.find({'title': {'$regex':search_term}}).limit(25)`

Comment: Please note that I'm using Python, not Mongo shell. $ is not Python syntax.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, looks like your last line actually works, it just separates upper and lowercase letters. :)

Comment: @Gabriel : if you want case insensitive search, please add '$options':'i'... You can see the syntax in my answer...

Comment: Yes, I saw it, thank you. It just had some issues and there was a \u200c\u200b between the '$options' and the : and it didn't get it. But I re-typed that part and now it works perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

#### $text

You can perform a text search using `$text` & `$search`. You first need to set a text index, then use it:

```
$ db.docs.createIndex( { title: "text" } )
$ db.docs.find( { $text: { $search: "search_term" } } )
```

#### $regex

You may also use `$regex`, as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10616781/641627

```
$ db.users.findOne({"username" : {$regex : ".*son.*"}});
```

#### Both solutions compared

- [Full Text Search vs. Regular Expressions](https://dzone.com/articles/mongodb-full-text-search-vs)

> ... The regular expression search takes longer for queries with just a
>   few results while the full text search gets faster and is clearly
>   superior in those cases.

Comment: The $ is invalid syntax in Python. And if I remove it, I get a NameError: name 'title' is not defined message.

Comment: And how do you insert a variable into the regex string? That's basically the point of my post.

Comment: in python, you'd put the $ characters in quotes, I don't see what wouldn't work