# Mongoose not returning Regex substrings

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
Reference.find(
            {$and: [
                {'url': url},
                {"text" : {$regex : text, '$options' : 'i'}}
            ]})
```

Whenever I test out `text` with 'Hello World', I get back documents that have that text exactly. However, if I were to do 'Hello Worl', I get nothing back, even with the same `url`. I've tried numerous implementations of ReGex, and so far none have worked. I'm using Mongo 3.2.11 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following string `'.*content.*'` or regex format `/.*content.*/`, which are the widely supported regex formats.

Also, see [Checking if a field contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610131/checking-if-a-field-contains-a-string)