# Create a 'contains' query using Java and MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm trying to follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610131/checking-if-a-field-contains-a-string#10616781) to create a "contains" query in Java. The problem is it's giving me an error.

At the moment i have the following code:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = null;
DBCursor cursor = null;

mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("bd-films");
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("films");

DBObject query = new BasicDBObject({"title" : {$regex : "name"}});         
cursor = coll.find(query);
```

The error it gives me is in the 'query' line:

```
Syntax error on token ""title"", invalid Label
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
```

I use the cursor for inserting it into a JTable.
Driver: mongo-java-driver-3.4.2
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe your query should look like this...


`DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("title", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "name"));`

Comment: Solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use new `Document` and `MongoCollection` api's for java driver 3.x version.

```
 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
 MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("bd-films");
 MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection("films");
 List<Document> results  = coll.find(Filters.regex("title", "name")).into(new ArrayList<>())
```

For accesssing `MongoCursor`,

```
FindIterable<Document> results  = coll.find(Filters.regex("title", "name"));
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = results.iterator();
```