# MongoDB query to search for users with best match?

Tags: mongodb, find

I have a users collection which contains documents with name key. I have data of users as follow:

**name**

```
halex
alex
galexi
joe alex
```

I need to apply find() query for alex. 
My query is:

```
db.users.find({name:"alex"});
```

In my result I get the alex at 3rd position.

I want it on 1st position because of the exact match.
Example:

```
alex
halex
joe alex
galexi
```

Comment: That query should return just two items, what do you mean?

Comment: I want it as mySQL like operator

Comment: Oh I understand. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610131/checking-if-a-field-contains-a-string

Comment: Yes, but I want my exact match on top and rest below it.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/query/text/#return-the-text-search-score