# How to search for text and print respective ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am making a website in which there is a function which will take an input and search for the text on mongoDB. I want to print all the user names which have such texts in their data.

I have tried looking up the official documentation and making changes to find a solution but nothing has helped so far.

```
// Search
router.post('/search', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.body;
    console.log(name);
    //I want to get the username and that specific data printed which is inside an array called books
    const Results = User.find( { $text: { $search: name } } );
    console.log(Results);
    res.redirect('borrow');
});
```

The actual result is nothing as I am not able to progress any further. The expected result is to get an multi-dimensional array which will have the user and the corresponding book.

For example if I have 2 people 
User 1 has books:
Harry Potter
Angels and Demons
Shy Harry

User 2 has books:
Harry Bad

If I search for harry then I want to store all the users which harry along with the books.

Comment: You'll need to update the question with some sample data and sample output that you want to achieve. Have a look at [**$regex**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) and this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610131/checking-if-a-field-contains-a-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610131/checking-if-a-field-contains-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes in code. So use code below.

```
router.post('/search', ensureAuthenticated, async(req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.body;
    console.log(name);
    //I want to get the username and that specific data printed which is inside an array called books
    const Results = await User.find( { $text: { $search: name } } );
    console.log(Results);
    res.redirect('borrow');
});
```

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: text index required for $text query
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/vaibhav2001/Documents/GitHub/Books4u/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:443:61)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at processMessage (/Users/vaibhav2001/Documents/GitHub/Books4u/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:364:10)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/vaibhav2001/Documents/GitHub/Books4u/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:533:15)

Comment: You have created text index in model. Can you send your model

Comment: UserSchema.index({name: 'text' });

Comment: const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    books: {
        type: Array,
        required: false
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;