# How to query in Mongo to find in a collection elements matching by the characters in the query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my Node API with MongoDB, I added a search feature to allow a client to search the profile collection for other users' profiles. At this time my search functionality takes in the query 3 params: first name (fn), last name (ln) and company (cp).

The results are from single param or from the combination of those 3. For now, it is the exact match like if I search `fn=joe` I get as results all profile with **Joe**.

My goal is to be able to find also writing like **J** or **Jo** becasue in the front end will be implemented a system to live search so when a user is starting typing the results come ups.
I need to modify my search to match the requirements but I don't have much knowledge in Mongo to do so.

My search feature:

```
const SearchController = {
    async getQuery(req, res) {
        try {
            // Set
            const set = {};

            // query params
            const { fn, ln, cp } = req.query;

            // RexExp to allow upper and lower case in the search
            // First name
            if (fn) {
                set["firstname"] = new RegExp(
                    "\\b" + req.query.fn + "\\b",
                    "i"
                );
            }

            // Last name
            if (ln) {
                set["surname"] = new RegExp("\\b" + req.query.ln + "\\b", "i");
            }

            // Company
            if (cp) {
                set["experience.company"] = new RegExp(
                    "\\b" + req.query.cp + "\\b",
                    "i"
                );
            }

            //
            if (Object.keys(set).length != 0) {
                // Searching the profile results
                const searchResult = await Profile.find(set, (err, doc) => {
                    return doc;
                });

                // No results
                if ((await searchResult).length === 0)
                    throw new ErrorHandlers.ErrorHandler(
                        404,
                        `Query do not provided any result`
                    );

                // Response
                res.status(200).json(searchResult);
            } else {
                // No result
                throw new ErrorHandlers.ErrorHandler(
                    404,
                    "Query do not provided any result"
                );
            }
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
        }
    }
};
```

The URL I'm composing to search:

```
URL/search?cp=...&fn=...&ln=...
```

As mentioned I can search only one or a combination between the three params and it is no case sensitive. I can use G as g.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a field contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610131/checking-if-a-field-contains-a-string)

Comment: I don't know honestly as I have no idea how to test it in my code can you show me one example with my code, please

Comment: I did this 
if (ln) {
                set["surname"] = new RegExp(
                    "\\b.*" + req.query.ln + ".*\\b",
                    "i"
                );
            }

Comment: If you've all 3 then do you need to get docs which matches all 3 criteria or anyone is also ok ?

Comment: What do you mean? If I search all of three I should get result matching the 3 criteria. If one or 2 just that.

Comment: Or I don't know actually what can be the best practice of this

Comment: it’s all about requirement if you’ve three criteria how to deal with it is that and operation between those or an or operation!!!

Comment: The requirements are those a user can search by digit only one of the params or 2 or 3 and any combination I can search by first name only or add 1 or 2 params