# Get comma exist document using mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

User collection below

```
[
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a6b381c13a090c70fc21b6"),
    "Name":"ABC"
    "processNumber" : "FEE 082517",
    "Process":"abc,cde"
    
       
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a6b381c13a090c70fc21b6"),
    "Name":"ABC"
    "processNumber" : "FEE 082517",
    "Process":"efg"
    
       
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a6b381c13a090c70fc21b6"),
    "Name":"ABC"
    "processNumber" : "FEE 082517",
    "Process":"123,3de"
    
       
  }
 ]
```

I have a user collection. I have to prepare a query to check the Process field whether it has any comma in value if it's there we have to return those documents

Expected output :

```
 [
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a6b381c13a090c70fc21b6"),
    "Name":"ABC"
    "processNumber" : "FEE 082517",
    "Process":"abc,cde"
    
       
  },
  
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a6b381c13a090c70fc21b6"),
    "Name":"ABC"
    "processNumber" : "FEE 082517",
    "Process":"123,3de"
    
       
  }
 ]
```

Comment: You can try using a regex query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a field contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610131/checking-if-a-field-contains-a-string)

Comment: Nope I want to get all the documents that have a comma(inside string)in Process field.

Comment: its same just use string whatever you want to search in field, `{ Process: { $regex: "," } }`

Comment: its working @turivishal thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search in field

```
{ Process: { $regex: "," } }
```

Query Should be

```
db.collection.find({ 'fieldname': { $regex: "," } })
```

@turivishal thanks for your answer