# MongoDB case insensitive "contains" operation, is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, graphql, hotchocolate

Here's my situation :

In my MongoDB Database, I have a list of objects.
Using an GraphQL API, I can search them using a filter.
This filter creates a 'contains' filter input with my value, 'bar' for example.
However, when the request is finished, I only get object that exactly matches the 'bar' sequences, even if I have other variants of the 'bar' sequence 'Bar, BAR, and so on...).

I've tried many implementations in my C# project (Custom Filtering, Custom Convention, ...) but nothing seems to be working.

here's an example of the request :

```
query SEARCH{
  search (            
    id: {
      wksUuid:"id1",
      prjUuid:"id2",
      fileUuid:"id3",
      fileVersion:"id4",
      stepLine:"id5"
    }        
  ) 
  {             
    foo
    (
      first: 30 
      after: null, 
      order: null, 
      where: {
        name:{
          contains: "bar"
        }
      }
    ) {                 
      pageInfo {                     
        hasNextPage                     
        endCursor                 
      }                 
      nodes {                                         
        name                               
      }             
    }         
  }     
}
```

This request is treated as such in my package :

```js
public async getFooItems(id: id, first?: string, cursor?: string, order?: any[], filters?: any): Promise<ResponseAPICall<any>> {
    const stringifiedId: string = JSON.stringify(id)?.replace(/"([^"]+)":/g, '$1:')
    
    const query: string = this.SEARCH.replace('$id', stringifiedId)
                                .replace('$cursor', cursor ? `"${cursor}"` : 'null')
                                .replace('$first', first ? first : 'null')
                                .replace('$order', (order && order?.length > 0) ? JSON.stringify(order)?.replace(/['"]+/g, '') : 'null')
                                .replace('$filters', filters ? JSON.stringify(filters)?.replace(/\"(\w+)\"\:/g, "$1:")?.replace(/\"([^\"]+)\":/g, '$1:') : 'null')
    const body: {query: string} = { query: query }
    const response: ResponseAPICall<any> = await this.httpRqs.post(this.apiUrl, body)

    return response
}
```

Is it even possible, using HotChocolate, MongoDB.Driver to apply a case insentive argument on the 'Contains' operation ?

- Custom String Filter (C#) : Implementation of a custom filter to override the contain operation, didn't work.
- Custom FilterConvention : Custom FilterConvention to override the current convention, Failed
- Followed [Extending Filtering](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/api-reference/extending-filtering), didn't work (the contain operation wasn't override on my request)
- Tried to edit the filter before the request is sent, failed (can't convert a StringType to a RegexType)

Edit : Here's how my object is resolved inside GraphQL, and I did try to extend said resolver to try and cofigure operations, but didn't succeed.

```cs
public class Foo: ObjectType<Foo>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Foo> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Field(_ => _.Id);
        descriptor.Field(_ => _.History);

        descriptor.Field(_ => _.Name);
        descriptor.Field(_ => _.IfcClassName);
        descriptor.Field(_ => _.IniesClassifCode);
        descriptor.Field(_ => _.Contributor);
        descriptor.Field(_ => _.Unit);
        descriptor.Field(_ => _.Lot);
        descriptor.Field(_ => _.BundleId);
        descriptor.Field(_ => _.RelatedContributorsId);
        descriptor.Field(_ => _.Qto);
        descriptor.Field(_ => _.RelatedEmptyComponentId);
        descriptor.Field(_ => _.InodeId);

        descriptor.Field<CbzContributorResolver>(_ => _.GetRelatedContributors(default, default))
            .Name("relatedContributors")
            .UsePaging()
            //.UseOffsetPaging()
            .UseSorting()
            .UseFiltering();
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly you should use GraphQL `variables` in your query instead of string substitution. Beyond that please share the resolver with the MongoDB query because that's where case sensitivity is going to come into play. The short answer is *yes* - MongoDB queries can be case insensitive. Remember - GraphQL is not a database, the db actually has to run the query that GraphQL has brought it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying `i` flag to make your regex case-insensitive.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10610461/5024706

Comment: I've tried, but the operation looks like this :
```js
filters: {
    name: {
        contains: "name"
    }
}
```

And apparently, adding the `i` doesn't work

Comment: Where did you add the flag? :)